# How to make sublime text autocomplete popup not disappear after a second?

Tags: plugins, autocomplete, sublimetext3

My sublime text autocomplete popup disappears after a second:

[image: see example here:]

How do I make it not disappear? Below is a list of sublime packages I installed and I don't know if fixing the settings would help. If so, can you tell me which package's settings I should fix and how?

[image]

Comment: **PLEASE DO NOT POST TEXT AS IMAGES**. Copy and paste the text into your question. Images are not searchable, and can not be interpreted by screen readers for those with visual impairments. Use the [edit] link to modify your question. See [this](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557/1426065) for more information.

Comment: @MattDMo : I definitely agree that code-related issues should be posted as text, but for this particular issue the OP is only showing GUI elements. The first image provides a visual reference for the auto-complete menu to which he referred, and the second is his plugin preference menu ( *which, as far as I know, SublimeText does not natively offer a way to output as text* ).

Comment: @OP : I recommend disabling your plugins with a [**binary search**](https://forum.sublimetext.com/t/plugin-host-has-exited-unexpectedly-build-3103-osx-10-11-3/17286/4) method, which should at least help you figure out if a particular plugin is causing the issue. Also, since your issue happens over a span of time, consider posting a GIF to demonstrate it. This can be done quite easily with something like [**ScreenToGIF**](https://screentogif.codeplex.com/).

Comment: Just noticed you're on OSX, so here are some [**alternatives**](http://alternativeto.net/software/screentogif/?platform=mac) to ScreenToGIF.

Comment: @Enteleform The Package Control user settings have a full list of installed packages.

Comment: @MattDMo : Oh cool! Good to know : )

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem and the cause of the problem was the `autosave` in sublime if you have it just disable it and suggestion won't be disappear